in node.js ESM I want to stub an exported module thats the default
I have a very simple auth middleware with an export default () anonymous function:
export default () => async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
       // some auth implementation... does not matter
    } else {
      throw new Error('No "Bearer" token passed as header')
    }

    next()
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
}


I want to stub this in my unit tests to just continue with next().
import express from 'express';
import supertest from 'supertest';
import { router } from "express-file-routing"
import auth from '../../middlewares/auth.js';
import sinon from 'sinon'

describe("/foo", () => {
    let app, request;
    
    before(async () => {
        app = express();
        app.use("/", await router())
        request = supertest(app);
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
   
        sinon.stub(auth()).callsFake((req, res, next) => next());
        // tried also ...
        // sinon.replace(auth, 'default', () => (req, res, next) => next());
});
//... test continue

But these are not working. I am getting TypeError: sinon.stub(...).callsFake is not a function
or
 TypeError: Cannot replace non-existent property default. Perhaps you meant sandbox.define()? when I try with sinon.replace

sinon.replace(auth, 'default' doesn't make sense because auth is already default import, and you couldn't do this for * import because it's readonly. You cannot effectively mock esm modules without transpiling them to cjs or using custom esm loaders. Sinon isn't responsible for this. This is a reason to prefer jest as it provides module mocking out of the box

As @Estus Flask mentions, ES Modules have an immutable namespace. This basically means you cannot assign/overwrite an export. What you can do is using a module loader, as described in this Sinon article.
If using Quibble, the resulting code looks like this:
describe("main module", () => {
  let mocked, main;

  before(() => {
    mocked = sinon.fake.returns("mocked");
    quibble("./other", { toBeMocked: mocked });
    ({ main } = require("./main"));
  });

  it("should mock", () => {
    main();
    expect(mocked.called).to.be.true;
  });
});

Full working example: https://github.com/fatso83/sinon-swc-bug/tree/esm-no-ts
The important bit for Mocha is specifying the loader in .mocharc.json:
{
  "spec": [
    "src/**/*.{spec,test}.js"
  ],
  "loader": "quibble"
}

